# b2body and b2fixture into array

Tags: arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray, box2d

can i adding b2body or b2fixture into NSmutableArray or NSArray.?
i've been looking for some solutions, one of them says it should be insert into NSValue first then adding the value to nsmutable array. so i write this in my code:

```
// Create ball body 

          b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;   
          ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
          ballBodyDef.position.Set(0/PTM_RATIO, 300/PTM_RATIO);
            ballBodyDef.userData = [ballSpriteArray objectAtIndex:a];

        _ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);


        // Create circle shape on ball
        b2CircleShape circle;
        circle.m_radius = 30.0/PTM_RATIO;

        // Create shape definition and add to body
        b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
        ballShapeDef.shape = &circle; 
        ballShapeDef.density = 0.5f;  
        ballShapeDef.friction = 0.5f; 
        ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.6f; 
        _ballFixture = _ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);
        fixValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&_ballFixture objCType:@encode(struct b2Fixture)];
                   [ballFixtureArray addObject:fixValue];



        //memberi impulse awal terhadap bola
        b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(5, 10);
        _ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, ballBodyDef.position);
        bodyValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&_ballBody objCType:@encode(struct b2Body)];
        [ballBodyArray addObject:bodyValue];
```

to get every b2Fixture and b2body on that nsmutablearray i did like this in CCtouchBegan Method:

```
for(NSValue *val in ballFixtureArray)
{
    b2Fixture *ballFix;
    [val getValue:&ballFix];


    if (ballFix->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {
    //if([ballFixtureArray objectAtIndex:0]->TestPoint(locationWorld)){
        for (NSValue *bodyVal in ballBodyArray){
            b2MouseJointDef md;
            md.bodyA = _groundBody;
            b2Body *ballBody;
            [bodyVal getValue:&ballBody];
            md.bodyB = ballBody;
            md.target = locationWorld;
            md.collideConnected = true;
            md.maxForce = 1000.0f * ballBody->GetMass();
            _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)_world->CreateJoint(&md);
            ballBody->SetAwake(true);
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work, in other hand the application just crash when i touch every location on the screen..
is there somebody can help me..??
thnx before for every advance..
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use std::list or std::vector to store this classes. But if really need to store this classes in NSArray wrap them with NSObject:

```
@interface Wrapper : NSObject
{
   b2Body *body;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) b2Body *body;
@end
```